# Правильное ли по смыслу составлены предложения? Если нет, то как правильно?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

1)На окрайнах дороги рядом с машинами, на плотной прозрачной клеенке, длинными рядами лежали кусты смородины накрытые белой тканью или черными полиэтиленовыми мешками.

2)Из под некоторых тел медленно текли ручейки крови

3. Они разбившись на пары, выносили на носилках, что - то из леса, в спешке направляясь в сторону дороги

4)Это были реанимационные автомобили, машины аварийно спасательных служб, скорой медицинской помощи, следственно оперативных групп, телевизионщиков, вперемешку с обычным легковым транспортом

Comment: То, что вы хотите, называется редакторской правкой. Наш форум немного не про это. Я отредактирую данные предложения, но впредь буду голосовать за закрытие таких вопросов.

Comment: Я конечно вам очень благодарен, но куда мне тогда идти?

Comment: вообще-то редактура штука платная. Но есть группы в ВК, где бета-ридеры бесплатно редактируют чужие тексты, есть, полагаю, и соответствующие сайты.

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо вам, за ваш труд!

Answer (score 2):

1. На окраинах дороги, рядом с машинами, на плотной прозрачной клеенке длинными рядами лежали кусты смородины, накрытые белой тканью или черными полиэтиленовыми мешками. *(Это один из вариантов пунктуации, есть ещё.)*
2. Из-под некоторых тел медленно текли ручейки крови.
3. Они, разбившись на пары, выносили на носилках что-то из леса, спеша в сторону дороги.
4. Это были реанимационные автомобили, машины аварийно-спасательных служб, скорой медицинской помощи, следственно-оперативных групп, телевизионщиков — все вперемешку с обычным легковым транспортом.

Comment: Думаю, что надо ещё ***из-под*** поправить. (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова действительно, не углядел. Спасибо!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hU2MK3miuzs